# getting error : React Hook "useSpring" is called conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

when i run my below code, i am getting this error :  `React Hook "useSpring" is called conditionally` can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ? any help will be really appreciated, here i have mention my code,  i did some googling but didnt help me, thanks again in advance

```
import React from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Redirect,
    withRouter,
    NavLink
  } from "react-router-dom";
import ScrollToTop from "./scrollToTop";
import App from "./App";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import {useSpring, animated} from 'react-spring';

const LoginButton = () => {
    const { loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated, isLoading, error } = useAuth0();
    console.log('isLoading', isLoading, isAuthenticated, error)
    const isAuth = localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')
    console.log('isAuth', isAuth)
    if(!isAuth){
        if (isLoading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
          }
    
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            loginWithRedirect()
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', isAuthenticated)
        }
    }
    const scrolling = useSpring({
      from: { transform: "translate(60%,0)" },
      to: { transform: "translate(-60%,0)" },
      config: { duration: 2000 },
      reset: true
    });
   
    return (   
                        <div>
                            <animated.div style={scrolling}>testing</animated.div>;
                        </div>
    );
};
export default LoginButton;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to react hooks documentation:
`Rules of Hooks are JavaScript functions, but they impose two additional rules:`

> Only call Hooks at the top level. Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

> Only call Hooks from React function components. Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. (There is just one other valid place to call Hooks — your own custom Hooks. We’ll learn about them in a moment.)

More you can read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

You cant call hooks after `if` statement. You have to do like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Redirect,
    withRouter,
    NavLink
  } from "react-router-dom";
import ScrollToTop from "./scrollToTop";
import App from "./App";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import {useSpring, animated} from 'react-spring';

const LoginButton = () => {
    const { loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated, isLoading, error } = useAuth0();
const scrolling = useSpring({
      from: { transform: "translate(60%,0)" },
      to: { transform: "translate(-60%,0)" },
      config: { duration: 2000 },
      reset: true
    });
    console.log('isLoading', isLoading, isAuthenticated, error)
    const isAuth = localStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated')
    console.log('isAuth', isAuth)
    if(!isAuth){
        if (isLoading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
          }
    
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            loginWithRedirect()
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', isAuthenticated)
        }
    }
    
   
    return (   
                        <div>
                            <animated.div style={scrolling}>testing</animated.div>;
                        </div>
    );
};
export default LoginButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just swap the order of useSpring and if logic

```
const scrolling = useSpring({
  from: { transform: "translate(60%,0)" },
  to: { transform: "translate(-60%,0)" },
  config: { duration: 2000 },
  reset: true,
});

    if (!isAuth) {
      if (isLoading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      }
    
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        loginWithRedirect();
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("isAuthenticated", isAuthenticated);
      }
    }
```

Because in your code if isAuth is false, it will return Loading... and prevent useSpring hook to run which is against the react hooks principle